# After a certain number of rest post calls to another api my spring boot application received 400 bad request and empty data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am calling an external rest API X from my spring mvc web application Y . 
I am calling POST method over X from Y for data (nearabout 300 request continuously). 
Y is getting the data of first 95 post request only from X but after that receiving 400 Bad request exception. 
for e.g. if Y is sending data in order from 1-300 Y is getting back result of 1-95 , whereas if Y is sending data in reverse order i.e. 300-1 Y is receiving data from 300 - 206 and for the rest its again giving 400 Bad Request error.
I have checked the data of the server X through post request on postman and the data is there.
I did the same thing through php and I am receiving the data of the entire set from 1-300 in a go.
Can you please help me what could be possible problem with the spring boot application.
Things I have tried already : 
1. Increased my Java Heap Memory to 1024M but it didn't helped(the max java memory heap that rest call is generating is about 700M checked on JMC).

Comment: Do you have capabilities to check server X for logs? You might spot something in the server log of why it responds with 400. Also please elaborate. You state you send POST requests from Y to X, but when you tested with PHP you "received" the entire set? I guess you tried a GET request there or?

Comment: @AlexanderFalk : I do not have access to X as its a third party system. I have sent 300 POST request from my php app as well and I received the data of 300 request successfully from php app(just simple app to check whether i was receiving data from the server X).

Comment: Your PHP app and your Spring Boot app. Did they send the same POST request? Same size of data? And can you provide an example of the POST request (sanitized)? :)

Comment: @AlexanderFalk : Yes my both app sent the POST method to the server X looping over 300 data used with the POST request. And request data is same from both app. In Y app I have used this in a loop to get the response - ResponseEntity<MyClassMapper> response =
               restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,
                                     formEntity, MyClassMapper.class); And in PHP i am calling with curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); in a loop.

Comment: I have drilled down the data set that i am sending from my both app and the response as well .. And hence after that i put my question here to find out if there is any limitation or memeory issue(which is not evident in my scenario). anybody can help please..? I am stuck here.

Comment: Can you attach a snippet of the POST code you use to do the requests? :)

Comment: @AlexanderFalk I have posted the call for the post request through the app Y. It doesnt seem to be an issue with the post request or the data as i can get the data in chunks or in reverse order.. I was wondering if there is any application property that could be set or rather increased to process all the request without failure in spring boot